# Using pipe() in Pandas with class methods?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a class (*stored in dataanalysis.py*) that stores most of the methods I am going to use for my data analysis. Here is the code stored in this file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Trening:
    def __init__(self, Path):
        self.path = Path
        self.df = None

    def getDF(self):
        return self.df

    def loadData(self, fileName= "pilot1.csv"):
        filePath = str(self.path + fileName)
        df = pd.read_csv(filePath, skiprows=2, decimal=".")
        #return df
        self.df = df

    def dnfCountandReplace(self, Return=False):
        filt = self.df['FINISH'] == 'DNF'
        dnf = self.df[filt]

        dnf = dnf.replace('DNF', 1)
        dnf.to_csv('faenta.csv')
        self.df.replace('DNF', np.NaN, inplace=True)
        self.df.dropna(subset=['FINISH'], inplace=True)
        if Return:
            return dnf

    def changeDataType(self, Return=False):
        self.df["FINISH"] = self.df["FINISH"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
        self.df["INTER 1"] = self.df["INTER 1"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
        self.df["SECTION IM4-FINISH"] = self.df["SECTION IM4-FINISH"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
        self.df["COMMENT"] = self.df['COMMENT'].astype(str)
        self.df["COMMENT"] = self.df['COMMENT'].str.replace('1', 'COURSE 1')
        self.df["COMMENT"] = self.df['COMMENT'].str.replace('2', 'COURSE 2')
        self.df["COMMENT"] = self.df['COMMENT'].str.replace('9', 'STRAIGHT-GLIDING')
        pd.to_numeric(self.df['FINISH'], downcast='float', errors='raise')
        pd.to_numeric(self.df['INTER 1'], downcast='float', errors='raise')
        pd.to_numeric(self.df['SECTION IM4-FINISH'], downcast='float', errors='raise')
        if Return:
            return self.df


    def renameCommentToCourse(self, Return=False):
        self.df.rename(columns={'COMMENT': 'COURSE'}, inplace=True)
        if Return:
            return self.df

    def groupData(self, Return=False):
        self.df.groupby(['BIB#', 'COURSE'])['FINISH']
        if Return:
            return self.df

    def findTwoFastestRunsbyGroup(self, Return=False):
        self.df['FINISH'].nsmallest(2)
        if Return:
            return self.df

    def parseToCSV(self):
        self.df.to_csv('cool.csv')

    def calculateSpeed(self, Return=False):
        # (x2 - x1) / (t2 - t1)
        x2 = 2
        x1 = 0
        t1 = 0
        for i in self.df['INTER 1']:
            self.df['ENTRANCESPEED'] = (x2 - x1) / (self.df['INTER 1'] - t1)
        if Return:
            return self.df
```

During my PhD, I am probably going to run these class methods > 300 times but sometimes in different orders and combinations, depending on what result I seek to obtain. So my question is: Is there a way to group class/chain methods together so that I can call on the relevant ones when needed? I know Pandas has an interesting pipe() function but I don't understand how to use it. In the main.py file, I have the following code:

```
from models import Trening
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


pilot1 = Trening("/Users/cmagelssen/Desktop/DataAnalyse/data/pilot1/trening1/")
pilot1.loadData("PILOT1_SESSION2.csv")
pilot1.dnfCountandReplace(Return=True)
X = pilot1.changeDataType(Return=True)
pilot1.renameCommentToCourse(Return=True)
pilot1.groupData(Return=True)
pilot1.findTwoFastestRunsbyGroup(Return=True)
df = pilot1.calculateSpeed(Return=True)
plot = pilot1.getDF()
```

Does someone know how I can chain/group these methods together using the pipe()?

Best,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code. With any combination of function you prefer. Make sure if you are using GetDF at the end, all the function called in the pipeline edits self.df too.

```
pilot1 = Trening("/Users/cmagelssen/Desktop/DataAnalyse/data/pilot1/trening1/")
df = pilot1.loadData("PILOT1_SESSION2.csv")



df =df.pipe(pilot1.dnfCountandReplace, Return =True)\
   .pipe(pilot1.changeDataType, Return =True)\
   .pipe(pilot1.renameCommentToCourse, Return =True)\
   .pipe(pilot1.groupData, Return =True)\
   .pipe(pilot1.findTwoFastestRunsbyGroup, Return =True)\
   .pipe(pilot1.findTwoFastestRunsbyGroup, Return =True)\
   .pipe(pilot1.calculateSpeed, Return =True)\
   .pipe(pilot1.getDF)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm running into the following error when I tried to implement the code: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pipe' - Any idea? Pandas is installed.

Comment: You are not returning anything in loaddata function. Add `return df` statement at the end of loadData function.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks again. As you pointed out, the load data function did not return anything. I needed to make the following changes to make it work: `    def loadData(self, fileName= "pilot1.csv"):
        filePath = str(self.path + fileName)
        self.df = pd.read_csv(filePath, skiprows=2, decimal=".")
        return self.df`